# Implementing quick sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to programing. I am trying to implement the quick sort algorithm in Ruby. I can't find many examples online that I can decipher well enough to use as examples. I have it working with floats, integers and strings.
I need help getting it to work with duplicate items in the array.
For example it works well with:
    `[-13, 12, 589, 11, 0, 27, 36, 92, 7, -2, 1001]` 
But not with:
    `[3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]`

Thank you in advance!

```
def quick_sort(list, start_point = nil, end_point = nil)
  if start_point && end_point
    if start_point >= end_point
     return list
    end
    left = start_point
    right = end_point
    pivot = left
  else
    left = 0
    right = list.count - 1
    pivot = left
  end

  min = left
  max = right

  while left < right
    if list[pivot] < list[right]
      right -= 1
    else
      list[pivot], list[right] = list[right], list[pivot]
      pivot = right
    end

    if list[pivot] > list[left]
      left += 1
    else
      list[pivot], list[left] = list[left], list[pivot]
    pivot = left
    end
  end
  quick_sort(list, min, pivot -1) 
  quick_sort(list, pivot +1, max) 
end
```

Comment: You have [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quick_Sort#Ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the code you're using to determine the highest index value.

```
right = list.index(list[-1])
```

Which is basically saying "give me the index of the value in the last element" but the last element value is `3` and that unfortunately is also the value of the first element, so it's returning 0 (the first occurence of the value it finds).

Better would be...

```
right = list.count - 1
```

EDIT also, you should handle the condition of two values being the same when comparing the values... that condition should be treated the same as 'no swap required'

so instead of

```
if list[pivot] < list[right]
...
if list[pivot] > list[left]
```

do

```
if list[pivot] <= list[right]
...
if list[pivot] >= list[left]
```

Comment: Very good point, but with that changed, the method still does not work. I think the problem is that I am not handling for when pivot and left(or right) are pointing to the same value. All of the solutions I have tried to implement have not given me  the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I've edited my answer to correct that as well.  I've verified it runs correctly now.

Comment: Cool, so this works very well for this edge case. However this makes other more normal conditions fail. If you like, here is my github repository. https://github.com/NickTerrafranca/fun-coding-challenges/tree/master/sort/quicksort It contains an Rspec file that I am using for testing. Feel free to copy and run it. I have been playing with some ideas I have been reading about, namely the concept of using two or even three pivots.

Comment: I figured it out. I was trying too hard. All I needed was to have a single if/elsif/else block instead of the two if/else blocks. Thanks for your help!